# C++, what happens if file moved while being read?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, race-condition, file-access

How does C++ behave if it is reading a file (say a csv file with 20,000 lines) and halfway through the read, another process deletes the file (lets say it is an ifstream).

Do I get a seg fault, or does the vector I am storing the lines in just have 10,000 lines and no error to indicate that something went wrong?

Similarly, what happens if I am writing via ofstream and it gets interrupted by a deletion?  In that case, if the interrupt is halfway through, does my output file only contain the last 10,000 lines?

Comment: Why not just take a read lock on the file to prevent it from being moved while you have it open?

Comment: Windows (and I assume other operating systems) prevents one process from altering a file in use by another process (hence "Cannot delete this file" error).

Comment: Why don't you try it? `int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    std::cin.get(); }` Now try to delete the file before you input anything in the console.

Comment: Yes, as jrok says, try it and see what happens. Though you may get different results on different operating systems.

Comment: @jrok: with c/c++ you have to be carefull about learning by testing. there's a lot of implementation-defined and undefined behavior..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on an OS.

If you are on a Unix-y OS, you will continue reading/writing the data since deletion is merely an update to a containing directory and/or inode, so you don't affect the file's data.

HOWEVER, if the disk blocks where the file data resided may be re-used (again depends on the OS) by a newer file WHILE you are reading, you will basically read wrong file's data once you finish with the data in the buffer.

If you are on Windows, as  Seth Carnegie correctly noted in a comment, the file automatically gets locked (and thus undeletable) if it is opened for reading.

Comment: on a POSIX system blocks won't be reused if there's a process accessing the file.

Comment: good question.. NFS is not POSIX compilant, but my guess is that it's OK.

Comment: On a UNIX like OS the underlying Inodes will not be re-assigned until all hard links to them have been deleted. The affect of an open file is to keep the nodes alive. When the processes is gone (thus closing the file) the filesystem them becomes free to reuse them.

Comment: @LokiAstari - that is correct, but only on a local filesystem

Answer (score -1):

It is highly system dependent I guess. As Linux may continue working while Windows give you some headache.

Comment: Gotta love unsolicited microsoft bashing from clueless nitwits.

Comment: Yep windows will refuse to delete a file while it is in use.

Comment: That's why you have to reboot for almost any update in Windows.

Comment: (fanning flames)..and a kernel rebuild for almost any update in Unixes, (OK, until recently:)